# Application Insights doesn't load data pretty often

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insights in Azure very intense but very often I experience loading issues.
So many times when I want to inspect the logs, I find the following loading animation taking forever:

[image]

The interesting thing ist, that nothing is really "loading" in the background. You can see my dev tools here:

[image]

So waiting forever does not help - its not "slowly", it just does not load at all.
None of my http requests seems to be pending... is there anyone experiencing the same behaviour? Or could I have misconfigured anything?

Comment: In our local environment, we are able to see the logs in transaction search of a particular application insights.
 This might be a browser issue would mind checking in other browser or re-login to the portal again post clearing the cache of the browser.

Comment: I tried already different browsers, clearing the cache different profiles... very strange. It still persists...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this all the time.

- Press F12 (in Chrome) to open Dev Tools.
- Hold left click on the refresh icon in the tool bar.
- Click 'Empty cache and hard reload'.

The transactions will now load.

[image: Example from Chrome]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try this next time it happens!